# Convolutional neural network is a continous function?

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution, deconvolution

The question is: is  convolutional neural network architecture a continuous function? By convolutional I mean made of only convolutional layers. Intuitively I would say yes, since as far as I know the operation of convolution is continuous, but am I missing anything?
Also, does anybody know if this is the case also for transpose convolution?

Answer (score 1):

It is a mathematical property that, if a function is differentiable, then the function is continuous; but vice versa is not true.

Now, we know that CNNs are differentiable, which is why back propagation works. Thus, they are continuous functions (in fact, every neural net which is differentiable is continuous).